# Loading Multiple html pages (WebView) From the same activity and using the if / else clause

Tags: java, android, android-activity, webview

I'm new to android dev. I want to know if it is possible to load up to twenty html pages in the assets folder from one activity using the if/else clause statements.

I want it that when a button is clicked in another activity, it opens a WebView according to the Button number pressed. I'm thinking I will have to create an activity for each webViews, but I'd like to know if I can use just one java class, and one Webview layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm thinking I will have to create an activity for each webViews, but
>   I'd like to know if I can use just one java class, and one Webview
>   layout.

No, you don't have to create an activity for each webViews.

When you're in your first activity, you can pass data to the second with the URL containing the HTML file in the assets folder.

Assuming you have two HTML pages for two different buttons:

```
file:///android_asset/page_button_1.html
file:///android_asset/page_button_2.html
```

In your first activity, pass the right URL in the `onClick` event (example for button one):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("keyHTML","file:///android_asset/page_button_1.html");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in your webview activity :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String value = "file:///android_asset/default_page.html";
    if(extras !=null) {
       value = extras.getString("keyHTML");
    }
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.loadUrl(value);
}
```

Comment: thanks... suppose it is just one button - The GO Button. as in a custom soft keypad, and you want it that when a string (a number) is inputed into the TextView box, and the GO button is clicked. I can use the if / else clause statement on onClick method of the GO Button and input the code linking the WebViewActivity class above. It will work yes?

Comment: @OluleyeIResþektIdowu Yes, or you could use a switch statement.

Comment: Sorry to bother you aqain @ZouZou. Which is the default_page.html? Like does it have to be blank? or maybe it doesnt matter as long as I have input the right HTML page in the i.putExtra("keyHTML","file:///android_asset/page_button_1.html"). Please guide

Comment: @OluleyeIResþektIdowu I added this just if you can't retrieve the right URL (normally it won't appear) so it could be a page you create too like a 404 error page =)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can use single activity and a webView,and change content by if/else statements. [See docs.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for `loadUrl` and `loadData` methods of `WebView`.

Answer (score 0):

In one activity you have a webview and in the web view you can change the html pages with method `webview.loadUrl("http://developer.android.com/");`
just make the html pages in the asset folder and then load the same pages at run time according to your logic.
e.g

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your.html");
```